Handling Page Load Status in Safari Extension with Iframes and Programmatically Opened Tabs
I have a Safari extension with three scripts: contentscript, background, and popupscript. My functionality is designed to show the user if the page is still loading when they open the extension. This generally works well, but I encounter issues in two scenarios:
Programmatically Opened Tabs: Some websites open new tabs programmatically when the user clicks on a feature. In this scenario, when the user opens the extension in the newly created tab while the page is still loading, the extension incorrectly shows that the page is still loading even after it has completed.
Iframes: If the page contains iframes, the load complete status from the background script is sent to the popup script while the iframe elements are still loading.
Here is the relevant code I'm using:
Background Script
When the extension is opened while the webpage is still loading:
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.status === "complete") {
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "PageLoadedEvent", loadingCompleted: true });
  }
});

When the extension is opened after the page has already loaded:
const queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  let reqData = JSON.parse(request);
  let reqType = reqData?.requestType;

  browser.tabs.query(queryOptions, function (tab) {
    if (reqType === "getCurrentTabStatus") {
      let tabData = tab[0];
      let tabId = tabData.id;
      if (tabData.status === "complete") {
        browser.tabs.query(queryOptions, function (tabs) {
          browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
            type: "LoadCompleted",
            loadingCompleted: true
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });
});

Popup Script
let loadingCompleted = false;

function getCurrentTabStatus() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    JSON.stringify({
      requestType: "getCurrentTabStatus",
    }),
    function (response) {}
  );
}
getCurrentTabStatus();


browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
  if (response.type === "LoadCompleted" && response.loadingCompleted) {
    loadingCompleted = true;

  } else if (response.type === "PageLoadedEvent" && response.loadingCompleted) {
    if (!loadingCompleted) {
      loadingCompleted = true;
    }
  }
});

Issues
When a new tab is created programmatically by a website, the loadingCompleted boolean becomes true even before the code reaches the PageLoadedEvent if condition. This likely happens due to the focus change from the current tab to the newly opened tab.
The load complete status is sent while iframes are still loading, causing the extension to proceed prematurely.
Questions
How can I ensure the extension correctly tracks the page load status even when a new tab is opened programmatically?
How can I handle the scenario where iframes are still loading to avoid premature status updates?
Any guidance or solutions to handle these scenarios effectively would be greatly appreciated.

Use browser.webNavigation.onCompleted in the popup script, which will show events for the main tab and the iframes. Also you don't need the background script for this task, just do everything in the popup. Currently the background script unnecessarily wakes up on every navigation in every tab even when there's no popup.

I attempted to use browser.webNavigation.onCompleted in the popup script, but it did not trigger at all. It appears that this event is only available in the background script. Would it be more effective to implement browser.tabs.onUpdated in conjunction with this event and consider the load complete only when both events have fired?

You may be looking at the wrong console. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. It's also possible Safari doesn't implement webNavigation, in which case you can use browser.tabs.onUpdated in the popup. Anyway, avoid browser.tabs.onUpdated in the background script.

As you mentioned, browser.webNavigation.onCompleted works in the popup script, but just like tabs.onUpdated, this event also fires before the iframe elements on the webpage are fully loaded. Is there any other solution for this?

It fires for each iframe in this tab, which means you can detect when the last iframe has finished loading.

Thank you for your support. Regarding the use of browser.webNavigation.onCompleted in the popup script, I have two scenarios: one where the extension is opened while the page is still loading, and another where the extension is opened after the page has completely loaded. If I use the webNavigation event in the popup script, I won't be able to handle the second scenario effectively. This is because if the extension is opened after the page has fully loaded, the extension would miss the webNavigation.onCompleted event.

I see. Well then you'll have to observe in the background script indeed and store the status in browser.storage so that it remains after the background script automatrically terminates after 30 seconds.
